# How to use pysox to specify the bitrate when converting wav to mp3

Tags: python, audio

I can use pysox to convert the wav to mp3 using the following code:

```
def process_audio(in_name_wav):
    sox_in_file = pysox.CSoxStream(in_name_wav)
    tof = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.mp3')
    temp_out_file_name = tof.name
    tof.close()
    sox_signal = sox_in_file.get_signal()
    sox_out_file = pysox.CSoxStream(temp_out_file_name, 'w', sox_signal)
    chain = pysox.CEffectsChain(sox_in_file, sox_out_file)
    chain = normalize(chain)
    chain = make_louder(chain)
    chain.flow_effects()
    sox_out_file.close()
```

I checked that the default bitrate used by pysox for generating the  output file is 128kbps:

```
#mp3check -l a.mp3 
a.mp3:
mpeg 1.0 layer 3 44.1kHz 128kbps joint stereo no emph --- orig ----     4:27.46
```

How can I specify my choice of bitrate to pysox ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this can be done through CEncodingInfo class, by passing it

http://pythonhosted.org/pysox/reference.html#pysox.CEncodingInfo

using the CEncodingInfo.set_param function.

You can create an encoding info, and then pass it to CSoxStream.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: `encode = pysox.CEncodingInfo(22, 32); sox_out_file = pysox.CSoxStream(temp_out_file_name, 'w', sox_signal, encode)`; But got the following error message: **formats: mp3 can't encode MPEG audio (layer I, II or III) to 32-bit**

Comment: Did you try other encodings or bitrates ?

Comment: Yes. I tried bitrates : 64, 128, 256, 512. I get simiar message: ***formats: mp3 can't encode MPEG audio (layer I, II or III) to 64-bit, 128-bit, 256-bit, 512-bit***

Comment: And what do you get when running get_encoding() on the input ?

Comment: `print sox_in_file.get_encoding()`: **CencodingInfo(1,16,"Signed PCM","Signed Integer PCM",inf)**  @Baruch Oxman